# Postgres issue using json_populate_recordset function

Tags: postgresql

Here I have created a type to use `json_populate_recordset` function .

```
CREATE TYPE Visits_type AS
    (facilityId varchar,patientId varchar,encounterId numeric,patientClass varchar,admnDate varchar,dischargeDate varchar,practitionerId varchar,
     careLocationType varchar,careLocationCode varchar,specialtyCode varchar,status varchar,admitPractitionerId varchar,hpSeqNo varchar,admissionType varchar,assignedRoom varchar,assignedBed varchar,
     Firstname varchar,
     Patientname varchar,
     Firstnamelocal varchar,
     Patientnamelocal varchar,
     sex varchar,
     Dob varchar,
     Mobilenumber varchar,
     Emailid varchar,
     RegnFacilityid varchar);
```

following Sample sql and json is used:

```
SELECT * from json_populate_recordset(null::Visits_type, '[
  {
    "facilityId": "10","patientId": "GH00000940","encounterId": 100011770001,"patientClass": "OP","admnDate": "2015-05-17 17:25","dischargeDate": null,"practitionerId": "ALLEN","careLocationType": "C","careLocationCode": "CL11","specialtyCode": "SP11",   "status": "E",    "admitPractitionerId": null,    "hpSeqNo": 3796,    "admissionType": "First Visit",    "assignedRoom": "R1",    "assignedBed": null,    "firstName": "Suresh",    "patientName": "Suresh    Machwal",    "firstNameLocal": null,    "patientNameLocal": null,    "sex": "M",    "dob": "1970-05-17",    "mobileNumber": null,    "emailId": null,    "regnFacilityId": "GH"  },  {
    "facilityId": "10",
    "patientId": "GH00000940",
    "encounterId": 100011770001,
    "patientClass": "OP",
    "admnDate": "2015-05-17 17:25",
    "dischargeDate": null,
    "practitionerId": "ALLEN",
    "careLocationType": "C",
    "careLocationCode": "CL11",
    "specialtyCode": "SP11",
    "status": "E",
    "admitPractitionerId": null,
    "hpSeqNo": 3795,
    "admissionType": "First Visit",
    "assignedRoom": "R1",
    "assignedBed": null,
    "firstName": "Suresh",
    "patientName": "Suresh    Machwal",
    "firstNameLocal": null,
    "patientNameLocal": null,
    "sex": "M",
    "dob": "1970-05-17",
    "mobileNumber": null,
    "emailId": null,
    "regnFacilityId": "GH"
  }]');
```

The issue is that its returning null values for all the fields, except for then `dob`, `status` and `sex`.

Comment: i can see the actual values when i query.. but when the use  FOR I IN (SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::visits_type,visit_info->'visits'))
   LOOP  .. I get error i.patientID field is not available.    I is of TYPE visit_type which i created with double quotes

Answer (score 4):

You should be using double quotes when you create your type to keep your original case:

```
CREATE TYPE Visits_type AS
    ("facilityId" varchar,
     "patientId" varchar,
     "encounterId" numeric,
     "patientClass" varchar,
     "admnDate" varchar,
     "dischargeDate" varchar,
     "practitionerId" varchar,
     "careLocationType" varchar,
     "careLocationCode" varchar,
     "specialtyCode" varchar,
     "status" varchar,
     "admitPractitionerId" varchar,
     "hpSeqNo" varchar,
     "admissionType" varchar,
     "assignedRoom" varchar,
     "assignedBed" varchar,
     "Firstname" varchar,
     "Patientname" varchar,
     "Firstnamelocal" varchar,
     "Patientnamelocal" varchar,
     "sex" varchar,
     "Dob" varchar,
     "Mobilenumber" varchar,
     "Emailid" varchar,
     "RegnFacilityid" varchar);
```